# How can I change style of the original tabbed page bar (android with xamarin.forms)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

good morning,
I'm designing my first app in xamarin.forms, but I ran into a problem that is the style of the tabbedpage bar in android.
On iOS it works great, but on Android it has a different display, but I would like to make the homogeneous thing on both operating systems know how to do it?

Screen Android https://ibb.co/cYRLvc4
Screen iOS https://ibb.co/ysnxBr8

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom effect, first update your android target to 9.0 (and support libraries)
then, create the Routing Effect in your Forms solution:

using Xamarin.Forms;

```
namespace YourApp
{
    public class NoShiftEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public NoShiftEffect() : base("MyEffect.NoShiftEffect")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in Android, create a custom renderer:

```
using Android.Support.Design.BottomNavigation;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using yournamespace.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly:ResolutionGroupName ("MyEffect")]
[assembly:ExportEffect (typeof(NoShiftEffect), "NoShiftEffect")]
namespace yournamespace.Droid
{
    public class NoShiftEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached ()
        {
            if (!(Container.GetChildAt(0) is ViewGroup layout))
                return;

            if (!(layout.GetChildAt(1) is BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView))
                return;

            // This is what we set to adjust if the shifting happens
            bottomNavigationView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityLabeled;
        }

        protected override void OnDetached ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

finally, in your tabbde page:

```
<TabbedPage.Effects>
    <local:NoShiftEffect />
</TabbedPage.Effects>
```

Comment: where can I find the library (using Android.Support.Design.BottomNavigation) on Visual Studio for Mac ?? it only gives me this error

Comment: You need to update the Android Support Libraries to v28

Comment: Nice! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it helped you @FrancescoRusso:)